# What to return when catching an exception in c#

Tags: c#

This is probably quite a simple question, but what is the best practice for return types on a try-catch block? At the moment, I'm doing stuff like this:

```
 public List<SomeAttribute> FindAttributes(int id)
   {
       try
       {
            //Some query and some logic
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.Error(ex);
           return new List<SomeAttribute>();
       }
   }
```

Is there anything particularly awful about this? The exception will get logged, and the method will return an empty list - which the calling function can handle. Is it better to return null? If so why?

Comment: You might want to strongly consider letting the caller handle the error if there's no sensible value to return.

Comment: Question is: why catch the exception, you can throw it further...

Comment: This is an opinion based question, but it really depends on what you're doing in the catch.  Maybe you can recover and then return the actual requested data.  Maybe you want to return null as an error indication.  Maybe you want to re-throw.  It's hard to say based on your question.

Comment: How will the caller differentiate between "no results" and "an error occurred"? What happens if the caller continues using your empty list?

Comment: Well, the FindAttributes() method may be called in lots of places, and the most often the errors are to do with the server timeout or hitting some quota limit or something, so that's why I want to catch it in the method that's actually performing the query rather than all of the other places where that method is being called.

Comment: If you can't answer that question, you probably shouldn't catch the exception at all.

Answer (score 6):

In general one considers three strategies to handle *partial functions* (functions where only a subset of the input domain is valid): *Total*, *Defensive*, and *Nominal*.

## Total

That means that you always return an answer. In this case you can for instance think about returning a **`null`-pointer**, in the case of `String.IndexOf` for instance one returns `-1`.

**Advantages:**

- It is sometimes easier for a the caller not to think about potential errors. Sometimes the return value can be useful. For instance if you want to cut off a the first part of a string up (and including the first comma), you can code this as:

  ```
  string foo = "Foo,Bar"
  string foocut = foo.SubString(foo.IndexOf(',')+1); //Bar, in case no comma, it returns the entire string
  ```

  Thus resulting in more compact code. But on the other hand it's sometimes hard to determine what the best return value is.

**Disadvantages:**

- It requires *engineering* to determine the "*best*" return value. There are many options and each option will only be beneficial for a part of the callers.
- It is sometimes impossible to distinguish between valid output where nothing went wrong and the (default) output in case something went wrong.

## Defensive

Here you **throw an exception** (or **don't catch** the exception). It is up to a (domain-specific) caller to determine why the exception has been thrown and handle accurately. Util methods have in general not much knowledge about the system and thus don't know why the exception occurred.

**Advantages:**

- The exception can be handled by the caller with the best knowledge (thus some kind of "*chain of responsibilities*"). This can result in better error handling (providing useful messages to the user). Not "*An error has occurred in SQL query ...*", but "*The username already exists.*"

**Disadvantages:**

- Error handling is sometimes hard. Especially in C# where one doesn't need to annotate which exception can be thrown by a method. It is not easy to cover all kinds of exceptions. It is possible that an uncatched exception will return to the top `Main` call crashing the application. For some applications like a webserver, that's not always an option.

## Nominal

Here you document your methods and provide **precoditions**: in the documentation you specify what are the correct ways to use that method. This isn't always possible since sometimes the fact whether a method succeeds depends on external factor (the availability of a server, the type of OS,...). Factors a programmer doesn't necessarily controls.

**Advantages:**

- Results in well documented (and sometimes strictly) defined methods.
- Implementing the method (*callee*) is easier since it can *assume* everything will work fine.

**Disadvantages:**

- Not always possible (sometimes the result does depend on factors one cannot control).
- Writing the *caller* is harder, since it it has a contract that it will only call the method with the correct arguments.
- It is also hard to document all conditions as well as validating that each call satisfies them. Sometimes *code contracts* are used to handle validation (partially) automatic.

Most programs don't stick with one strategy but mix them: for instance some exceptions are handled total, others nominal and others defensive. Or some module follows the defensive strategy whereas the other uses nominal programming.